# Extract common functionality from controller

Tags: controller, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, httpcontext

I am unable to decide the best way to extract some functionality being used by multiple methods of multiple controller in my project

Common functionality

```
var myId = httpContext?.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "myId")?.Value;
//few operations and a couple of repository calls
//return the details
```

Now I am wondering should I move it to base controller? Should I create a static helper class? What is the best way to handle this?

Edit 1:
My attempt at resolving this:

```
public static class MyHelper
{   
    public static MyEntity? MyMethod(HttpContext httpContext, IMyRepo1 myRepo1,
        IMyRepo2 myRepo2)
    {
        var id = httpContext?.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "myId")?.Value;
        var a = _myRepo1.CallRepo1Method(); 
    //random local operations on var a 
    var result = _myRepo2.CallRepo2Method();
    return result;
    }
}

//Call from controller
var result = MyHelper.MyMethod(HttpContext, _myRepo1, _myRepo2);
```

Comment: I think MVC is a good start when our application is just in the beginning. Pls correct me if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my humble opinion, we should design the app to avoid high coupling, that means the query method should be based on the tables but not be based on the business for query requirement. I think the most ideal scenario is that, one table have a query sentence, and whenever a business is associate to this table, then using this query, and I also know in some terms it's impossible because our business is becoming more and more complex.

Let's coming back to your scenario, as far as I know, we can certainly define a controller to have the httpContext and then do a lot of query, then inject this controller into some other controllers or services, but I don't think it's a very good idea to combine so many logic into the controller, we should put the logic into Services and in controller, we call multiple services at most.

So if I were you, I will have a Service which received the `myId`, and execute one database query. If there were several database queries, then do all of them inside this service, if there were already existing several services for the database queries, then I might call the services one by one in the controller.

```
public class CountryController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMyHelper _myHelper;
    public CountryController(IMyHelper myHelper) { 
        _myHelper = myHelper;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new CountryViewModel();
        var date = _myHelper.operateRepo("myid");
        return View(model);
    }
}

public class MyHelper : IMyHelper
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyHelper> _logger;
    private readonly IRepoOne _repoOne;
    private readonly IRepoTwo _repoTwo;

    public MyHelper(ILogger<MyHelper> logger, IRepoOne repoOne, IRepoTwo repoTwo) {
        _logger = logger;
        _repoOne = repoOne;
        _repoTwo = repoTwo;
    }
    public string operateRepo(string id)
    {
        var res = _repoOne.xxmethod();
        //some operation on res here
        var res2 = _repoTwo.yymethod();
        //some opeartation here
        return "done";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tiny Wang, in my existing set up calls directly go from controller to repositories and if I want to continue the set up what do I do? I tried two things but not very satisfied.1. I made a constructor in my basecontroller and 2. I made a helper/utility but then I am having to send my repository object from my controller like NewMethod(id, IMyRepo1, IMyRepo2)

Comment: Hi Lucky, thanks for your kind reply, I think both of your operations are useful attempt. If I were you and if I want to reduce some code, I might create a new class tor provide a method which is injected IMyRepo1 so that I don't need to send IMyRepo1 from the controller to this method, I just need to send the id to the method. This will be of benefit when someday I have another similar requirement which also need to call this method, and in this new class I can put some other methods for different scenario.

Comment: And this will make the controller looks clearly, I just need one line of code to call the method in helper/utility class, and add a comment on this line to explain what data I tried to get via this method.

Comment: I am sorry may be I did not understand correctly. Lets say my set up in controller is like this var id = HttpContext.User.Claims // as show in my question
var a = _myRepo1.CallRepo1Method();
//random local operations on var a
var result = _myRepo2.CallRepo2Method();

//continue operations in controller with the final result
//return Ok(result.ToList());

Comment: My new static class is: public static class MyHelper
{   
    public static MyEntity? MyMethod(HttpContext httpContext, IMyRepo1 myRepo1,
        IMyRepo2 myRepo2)
    {
        var id = httpContext?.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "myId")?.Value;
        var a = _myRepo1.CallRepo1Method(); 
 //random local operations on var a 
 var result = _myRepo2.CallRepo2Method();
 return result;
    }
}

//Call from controller
var result = MyHelper.MyMethod(HttpContext, _myRepo1, _myRepo2);

Comment: A little benefit I get from doing in base controller is I can inject my dependencies for repo there itself and not send from my controller. But then all other calls are being made into nullable which I think is little ugly and also the need to bring the change to all controllers while this method is being used by subset of controller methods

Comment: could you pls help update your code snippets into your question so that we could have a good view? And I think it's not necessary for us the have a static method. Static method, hmmm let's see [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48869) here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255310/discussion-between-lucky-and-tiny-wang).

Comment: Hi, I already updated my post, and this is what I would do. I agree with what @marcospereira said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48869) that `write static methods only when they have no external dependencies (like database access, read files, emails and so on) to keep them as simple as possible`, so in the myHelper class I won't create static method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions and explanation!

Comment: thank you once again for your kind reply